# How to plot function with pattern-matched argument and catch-all definition that throws

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Consider the following function:

```
f[n_?NumericQ] := n;
f[args___] := Throw[{args}];
```

Then try to plot it:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[{Charting`Private`pvar$7957}] returned to top level.
> Hold[Throw[{Charting`Private`pvar$7957}]]

---

### Examination

If we now redefine `f` without the catch-all definition, and examine the behaviour of Plot, we find the following:

```
Clear[f];
f[n_?NumericQ] := n;
Reap@Plot[f[Sow[x]], {x, 1, 10}]
```

> {-Graphics-, {{1, 1.00018, **Charting`Private`pvar$8374**, 1., 1.17666, 1.36818, ..., 9.80849, 9.90733, 9.95675, 9.98147, 9.99382, 1.00276, 9.8054, 9.90424, 9.95367, 9.97838, 9.99073, 9.99691}}}

So why does `Plot` evaluate function with argument `` Charting`Private`pvar$... ``, and moreover why after 2 numerical substitutions?

How can `Plot` work with a function that has a catch-all definition which throws error if its other patterns aren't matched?

I would like, if possible, to have `Plot` throw if the pattern checks of `f` don't match, and `Catch` it on a higher level.

Comment: `Plot[Catch[f[x]], {x, 1, 10}]` ?

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, I forgot to mention I would like, if possible, to have `Plot` throw if the pattern checks of `f` don't match, and `Catch` it on a higher level.
If I catch the error inside `Plot` everything will seem as if it worked right and a plot will be created, even when all of the plot's sampled `[x]`s evaluate to `Throw`.

Comment: Use `f[n_?NumericQ] := n; f[_Symbol] = Null; f[args___] := Throw[{args}]`?

Comment: @Carl This seems to be what I'm looking for! Using head `Symbol` in patterns will do it for me I'm pretty certain, thanks! Any feedback on why that symbol is evaluated as `x`? Isn't that kind of an odd behaviour or am I missing something?